# Installing ethereum node on Raspberry pi errors

Tags: go-ethereum, installation, raspberry-pi

I have been following the steps of this guide: http://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html

but i get stuck on the "make geth" command, where my RPI outputs this error:

```
build/env.sh go install -v -ldflags '-X main.gitCommit c541b38fb36587d23c60f5e2f2b9b3c8700ec489' ./cmd/geth
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types
build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types/transaction.go:39: undefined: atomic.Value
build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types/transaction.go:40: undefined: atomic.Value
build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types/transaction.go:41: undefined: atomic.Value
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'geth' failed
make: *** [geth] Error 2
```

What could be wrong ?!

***EDIT***

after usign the updated git repo here is the erro i get:

```
build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/build/azure.go:23:2: cannot find package "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage (from $GOROOT)
        /home/pi/bin/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage (from $GOPATH)
build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/build/pgp.go:27:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp (from $GOROOT)
        /home/pi/bin/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp (from $GOPATH)
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'geth' failed
make: *** [geth] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** : i think this issue was resolved in the updated geth version by removing the elliptic.P224 usage so you are using an old release. I think the Tuto you follow is not updated. I suggest you to repeat the steps by using :

```
git clone -b release/1.5 https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
```

**Solution for old release :**
I've the same problem i resolved it by following the steps below(based on a problem raised on official github repos) :

1-First try a `make clean`.
2-try to install :`brew install gmp` or `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev` 
3-Remove all references to elliptic.P224 from files crypto/ecies/asn1.go and  crypto/ecies/ecies_test.go

Comment: sudo apt-get isntall libgmp dones't work: unable to locate the package

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev or sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev

Comment: I have tried with the newer vesion and i know get another error, see my edit on my post

Comment: Try the master and check this issue :https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3277