# Installing geth on Raspberry Pi 3 - cannot allocate memory error

Tags: go-ethereum, installation, raspberry-pi

I've been using [this script](https://github.com/EthEmbedded/Raspi-Eth-Install/blob/master/geth-installer.sh) to attempt to install geth on a [Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/).

It seems to work ok until part way through the build:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/go-ethereum $ make geth
build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install ./cmd/geth
>>> /usr/lib/go-1.7/bin/go install -ldflags -X main.gitCommit=bdef758d5c6d397584d0c35e53d6f6c318e61351 -v ./cmd/geth
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth
/usr/lib/go-1.7/pkg/tool/linux_arm/link: running gcc failed: fork/exec /usr/bin/gcc: cannot allocate memory

util.go:43: exit status 2
exit status 1
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'geth' failed
make: *** [geth] Error 1
```

It is saying `cannot allocate memory` - there is ~8GiB free on the SD card (1GB RAM).

Can anyone recreate this error? What tips are there for debugging/fixing?

N.b. This question is similar to [Installing ethereum node on Raspberry pi errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/installing-ethereum-node-on-raspberry-pi-errors).

Also, a similar problem was reported here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-print-connector/zF_xyViClLM

Comment: How much memory (i.e. RAM) is available before building? (Run `free -h`.) Are there any memory-consuming processes you could kill first? (Run `top`, then press `M` to order by memory use.)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks that was it thanks; I only had 236M free...... thanks!

Comment: Thanks - I've added a few more details in case they're useful to anyone else :-)

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/raspberry-pi-support-on-ethereum/12458#12458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What tips are there for debugging/fixing?

These suggestions aren't specific to Ethereum/Geth/etc., but they may be of use to someone seeing the same problem in future.

The error was complaining about a lack of memory. (Where "memory" means RAM, not harddisk space.)

```
/usr/lib/go-1.7/pkg/tool/linux_arm/link: running gcc failed: fork/exec 
/usr/bin/gcc: cannot allocate memory
```

Even if you know how much memory your system has, first check how much of it is actually available:

- `free -h`, or
- `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree`

If there's what you'd consider to be not enough, see if you can free any up by assessing which processes are using it:

- `top`, then `M` to order by memory use.

Once you've selected any **non-critical** processes you don't need, kill them:

- `kill -15 <pid>`, where `pid` is the process id.

(Note we're using signal number `-15`, which equates to `SIGTERM`, rather than `-9`, which is `SIGKILL`. This way we give the process a chance to be notified of the signal - if it has a handler installed - and clean up gracefully.)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I found this answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-to-set-up-swap-space and was able to compile and run geth on a Rasp B with 512 MB ram